# Mercurial: where to put the "style file" so it can (easily) be used on all my projects

Tags: mercurial

Just learning about mercurial's `--style` and `--template` options that can be used on `hg log` and `hg tip` and I find them to be extremely helpful, but I can't figure out where to put my "style files"

I have a "style file" which will allow me to do a `hg tip --style ./my-style` — and it works great.  Except that I don't want this style file to be a file under my project.  And I want to be able to use it on all my projects.  I don't want it to be the default style (so it isn't an option to update `.hgrc`'s style field).

**Where should I put this file?**  Do I just need to put in in my home directory and refer to it like `hg tip --style ~/my-style`?

Not sure if you need to know, but although I use Windows at times, I mostly use Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where you put it. I usually organize my hg-related files in a single directory in my home directory which I call `~/.hgstuff`. I have an `hgignore` and some other common settings files in there.

You can also use the `[alias]` section to define aliases which will automatically apply your style file. Eg:

```
[alias]
stip = tip --style ~/.hgstuff/my-style
```

Then you just need to run `hg stip` to get your stylized version.

If you want to use the style for every command, you can set it in the `[ui]` section:

```
[ui]
style = ~/.hgstuff/my-style
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also stick it in Mercurial's template directory (C:\program files\mercurial\templates or c:\program files\tortoisehg\templates if using tortoisehg, or /usr/share/mercurial/templates on Ubuntu) to make it available system-wide.